# PyTorch preferred way to copy a tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, copy, tensor

There seems to be several ways to create a copy of a tensor in PyTorch, including

```
y = tensor.new_tensor(x) #a

y = x.clone().detach() #b

y = torch.empty_like(x).copy_(x) #c

y = torch.tensor(x) #d
```

`b` is explicitly preferred over `a` and `d` according to a UserWarning I get if I execute either `a` or `d`. Why is it preferred? Performance? I'd argue it's less readable.

Any reasons for/against using `c`?

Comment: one advantage of `b` is that it makes explicit the fact that `y` is no more part of computational graph i.e. doesn't require gradient. `c` is different from all 3 in that `y` still requires grad.

Comment: How about `torch.empty_like(x).copy_(x).detach()` - is that the same as `a/b/d`? I recognize this is not a smart way to do it, I'm just trying to understand how the autograd works. I'm confused by the [docs for `clone()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.clone) which say "Unlike copy_(), this function is recorded in the computation graph," which made me think `copy_()` would not require grad.

Comment: There's a pretty explicit note in the docs: `When data is a tensor x, new_tensor() reads out ‘the data’ from whatever it is passed, and constructs a leaf variable. Therefore tensor.new_tensor(x) is equivalent to x.clone().detach() and tensor.new_tensor(x, requires_grad=True) is equivalent to x.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True). The equivalents using clone() and detach() are recommended.`

Comment: Pytorch '1.1.0'  recommends #b now and shows warning in #d

Comment: @ManojAcharya maybe consider adding your comment as an answer here.

Comment: what about `.clone()` by itself?

Comment: @CharlieParker `.clone()` keeps graph structure but creates a new memory, i.e., its grad will backpropagate to the original object from the independent cloning data; it is just the opposite of `.detach()`, which is discarded from the original graph but share the memory address. Generally, `.clone()` is suitable to construct simple repetitive neural layers with the same function, e.g., the Multi-Heads in Transformer.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Use `.clone().detach()` (or preferrably `.detach().clone()`)

> If you first detach the tensor and then clone it, the computation path is not copied, the other way around it is copied and then abandoned. Thus, `.detach().clone()` is very slightly more efficient.-- [pytorch forums](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/difference-between-detach-clone-and-clone-detach/34173)

as it's slightly fast and explicit in what it does.

---

Using [`perflot`](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot/), I plotted the timing of various methods to copy a pytorch tensor.

```
y = tensor.new_tensor(x) # method a

y = x.clone().detach() # method b

y = torch.empty_like(x).copy_(x) # method c

y = torch.tensor(x) # method d

y = x.detach().clone() # method e
```

The x-axis is the dimension of tensor created, y-axis shows the time. The graph is in linear scale. As you can clearly see, the `tensor()` or `new_tensor()` takes more time compared to other three methods.

[image]

*Note:* In multiple runs, I noticed that out of b, c, e, any method can have lowest time. The same is true for a and d. But, the methods b, c, e consistently have lower timing than a and d.

```
import torch
import perfplot

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: torch.randn(n),
    kernels=[
        lambda a: a.new_tensor(a),
        lambda a: a.clone().detach(),
        lambda a: torch.empty_like(a).copy_(a),
        lambda a: torch.tensor(a),
        lambda a: a.detach().clone(),
    ],
    labels=["new_tensor()", "clone().detach()", "empty_like().copy()", "tensor()", "detach().clone()"],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(15)],
    xlabel="len(a)",
    logx=False,
    logy=False,
    title='Timing comparison for copying a pytorch tensor',
)
```

Comment: Stupid question, but why do we need clone()? Do otherwise both tensors point to the same raw data?

Comment: Ah yes, see https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/clone-and-detach-in-v0-4-0/16861/2?u=gebbissimo

Answer (score 25):

According to [Pytorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.new_tensor) #a and #b are equivalent. It also say that

> The equivalents using clone() and detach() are recommended.

So if you want to copy a tensor and detach from the computation graph you should be using

```
y = x.clone().detach()
```

Since it is the cleanest and most readable way. With all other version there is some hidden logic and it is also not 100% clear what happens to the computation graph and gradient propagation.

Regarding #c: It seems a bit to complicated for what is actually done and could also introduces some overhead but I am not sure about that.

Edit: Since it was asked in the comments why not just use `.clone()`.

From the [pytorch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.clone)

> Unlike copy_(), this function is recorded in the computation graph. Gradients propagating to the cloned tensor will propagate to the original tensor.

So while `.clone()` returns a copy of the data it keeps the computation graph and records the clone operation in it. As mentioned this will lead to gradient propagated to the cloned tensor also propagate to the original tensor. This behavior can lead to errors and is not obvious. Because of these possible side effects a tensor should only be cloned via `.clone()` if this behavior is explicitly wanted. To avoid these side effects the `.detach()` is added to disconnect the computation graph from the cloned tensor.

Since in general for a copy operation one wants a clean copy which can't lead to unforeseen side effects the preferred way to copy a tensors is `.clone().detach()`.

Comment: Why is `detach()` required?

Comment: From the docs "Unlike copy_(), this function is recorded in the computation graph. Gradients propagating to the cloned tensor will propagate to the original tensor.". So to really copy the tensor you want to detach it, or you might get some unwanted gradient updates, you don't know where they coming from.

Comment: what about `.clone()` by itself?

Comment: I added some text explaining why not clone by itself. Hope this answers the question.

Answer (score 7):

One example to check if the tensor is copied:

```
import torch
def samestorage(x,y):
    if x.storage().data_ptr()==y.storage().data_ptr():
        print("same storage")
    else:
        print("different storage")
a = torch.ones((1,2), requires_grad=True)
print(a)
b = a
c = a.data
d = a.detach()
e = a.data.clone()
f = a.clone()
g = a.detach().clone()
i = torch.empty_like(a).copy_(a)
j = torch.tensor(a) # UserWarning: To copy construct from a tensor, it is recommended to use sourceTensor.clone().detach() or sourceTensor.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True), rather than torch.tensor(sourceTensor).


print("a:",end='');samestorage(a,a)
print("b:",end='');samestorage(a,b)
print("c:",end='');samestorage(a,c)
print("d:",end='');samestorage(a,d)
print("e:",end='');samestorage(a,e)
print("f:",end='');samestorage(a,f)
print("g:",end='');samestorage(a,g)
print("i:",end='');samestorage(a,i)
```

Out:

```
tensor([[1., 1.]], requires_grad=True)
a:same storage
b:same storage
c:same storage
d:same storage
e:different storage
f:different storage
g:different storage
i:different storage
j:different storage
```

The tensor is *copied* if the *different storage* shows up.
PyTorch has almost 100 different constructors, so you may add many more ways.

If I would need to copy a tensor I would just use `copy()`, this copies also the AD related info, so if I would need to remove AD related info I would use:

```
y = x.clone().detach()
```

Comment: Use "if x.untyped_storage().data_ptr()==y.untyped_storage().data_ptr():" instead of "if x.storage().data_ptr()==y.storage().data_ptr():" to avoid deprecated TypedStorage.

Answer (score 4):

Pytorch '1.1.0' recommends #b now and shows warning for #d

Comment: what about `.clone()` by itself?

Comment: clone by itself will also keep the variable attached to the original graph

Comment: @CharlieParker see comments in the original question, and also answer from Nopileos