# Pytorch RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, gradient, reinforcement-learning

This code is built up as follows: My robot takes a picture, some tf computer vision model calculates where in the picture the target object starts. This information (x1 and x2 coordinate) is passed to a pytorch model. It should learn to predict the correct motor activations, in order to get closer to the target. After the movement is executed, the robot takes a picture again and the tf cv model should calculate whether the motor activation brought the robot closer to the desired state (x1 at 10, x2 coordinate at at31)

However every time i run the code pytorch is not able to calculate the gradients.

I'm wondering if this is some data-type problem or if it is a more general one: Is it impossible to calculate the gradients if the loss is not calculated directly from the pytorch network's output?

Any help and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
#define policy model (model to learn a policy for my robot)
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F 
class policy_gradient_model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(policy_gradient_model, self).__init__()
        self.fc0 = nn.Linear(2, 2)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2, 32)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(32, 64)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64,32)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(32,32)
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(32, 2)
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.fc0(x)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc4(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc5(x))
        return x

policy_model = policy_gradient_model().double()
print(policy_model)
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(policy_model.parameters(), lr=0.005, betas=(0.9,0.999), eps=1e-08, weight_decay=0.01, amsgrad=False)

#make robot move as predicted by pytorch network (not all code included)
def move(motor_controls):
#define curvature
 #   motor_controls[0] = sigmoid(motor_controls[0])
    activation_left = 1+(motor_controls[0])*99
    activation_right = 1+(1- motor_controls[0])*99

    print("activation left:", activation_left, ". activation right:",activation_right, ". time:", motor_controls[1]*100)

#start movement

#main
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
from torch.autograd import Variable
print("start training")
losses=[]
losses_end_of_epoch=[]
number_of_steps_each_epoch=[]
loss_function = nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean')

#each epoch
for epoch in range(2):
    count=0
    target_reached=False
    while target_reached==False:
        print("epoch: ", epoch, ". step:", count)
###process and take picture
        indices = process_picture()
###binary_network(sliced)=indices as input for policy model
        optimizer.zero_grad()
###output: 1 for curvature, 1 for duration of movement
        motor_controls = policy_model(Variable(torch.from_numpy(indices))).detach().numpy()
        print("NO TANH output for motor: 1)activation left, 2)time ", motor_controls)
        motor_controls[0] = np.tanh(motor_controls[0])
        motor_controls[1] = np.tanh(motor_controls[1])
        print("TANH output for motor: 1)activation left, 2)time ", motor_controls)
###execute suggested action
        move(motor_controls)
###take and process picture2 (after movement)
        indices = (process_picture())
###loss=(binary_network(picture2) - desired
        print("calculate loss")
        print("idx", indices, type(torch.tensor(indices)))
     #   loss = 0
      #  loss = (indices[0]-10)**2+(indices[1]-31)**2
       # loss = loss/2
        print("shape of indices", indices.shape)
        array=np.zeros((1,2))
        array[0]=indices
        print(array.shape, type(array))
        array2 = torch.ones([1,2])
        loss = loss_function(torch.tensor(array).double(), torch.tensor([[10.0,31.0]]).double()).float()
        print("loss: ", loss, type(loss), loss.shape)
       # array2[0] = loss_function(torch.tensor(array).double(), 
        torch.tensor([[10.0,31.0]]).double()).float()
        losses.append(loss)
#start line causing the error-message (still part of main)
###calculate gradients
        loss.backward()
#end line causing the error-message (still part of main)

###apply gradients        
        optimizer.step()

#Output (so far as intented) (not all included)

#calculate loss
idx [14. 15.] <class 'torch.Tensor'>
shape of indices (2,)
(1, 2) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
loss:  tensor(136.) <class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([])

#Error Message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/GradientPolicyLearning/PolicyModel.py", line 259, in <module>
    array2.backward()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 134, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 99, in 
 backward
    allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

Answer (score 12):

If you call `.detach()` on  the prediction, that will delete the gradients. Since you are first getting indices from the model and then trying to backprop the error, I would suggest

```py
prediction = policy_model(torch.from_numpy(indices))
motor_controls = prediction.clone().detach().numpy()
```

This would keep the predictions as it is with the calculated gradients that can be backproped.
Now you can do

```py
loss = loss_function(prediction, torch.tensor([[10.0,31.0]]).double()).float()
```

Note, you might wanna call double of the prediction if it throws an error.

Comment: Thank your for your answer! So you do not think that it will be a problem that I calculate the error only after "moving the robot and inferring the (new state-desired state)"  and not directly from the output of the network?

Comment: Wait, I just corrected the mistake in code, that one of the tensor in the loss should have gradients for the loss to have gradients that can be backproped. I haven't studied RL (yet) and hence I don't know how policy gradient is implemented. If I misguided you on that, my apologies

Comment: Don't worry. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I could just try your suggestion, but unfortunately it would not help. Instead of
"loss = loss_function(prediction, torch.tensor([[10.0,31.0]]).double()).float()"
as suggested by you i use
"loss = loss_function(torch.from_numpy(indices).double(), torch.tensor([[15.0,26.0]]).double()).float()"
because i do not want to reward the output directly but i want to reward the effect that the network output (converted to motor activation) has on the state of the network.
Basically I still get the following error:
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

Comment: As I said, for backprop go work, the loss function should take in one argument with gradients. Basically, the conversion of model output to it's effect has to be a function that works on the model output to conserve the gradients. That's exactly why I said I don't know how policy gradients does this exact thing.

Comment: "Use .clone().detach() (or preferrably .detach().clone())."

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55266154/pytorch-preferred-way-to-copy-a-tensor

Answer (score 7):

**simple solution**, turn on the Context Manager that sets gradient calculation to ON, if it is off

```
torch.set_grad_enabled(True)  # Context-manager
```

Answer (score 6):

Following worked for me:

```
loss.requires_grad = True
loss.backward()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Its 2024, this solution worked for me also.

Answer (score 5):

It is indeed impossible to calculate the gradients if the loss is not calculated directly from the PyTorch network's output because then you would not be able to apply the chain rule which is used to optimise the gradients.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!
I have trouble understanding how the error is backtracked to change the weights.. Shouldn't it just be important to the network how large the error was but not how it was calculated or what exactly it resulted from? I mean isn't it that I could also write my own loss function. How should Pytorch/TF then know how the calculated error/loss is connected to the input and the weights of the network?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all your inputs into the NN, the output of NN and ground truth/target values are all of type torch.tensor and not list, numpy.array or any other iterable.

Also, make sure that they are not converted to list or numpy.array at any point either.

In my case, I got this error because I performed list comprehension on the tensor containing predicted values from NN. I did this to get the max value in each row.  Then, converted the list back to a torch.tensor. before calculating the loss.

This back and forth conversion disables the gradient calculations

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got past this error by specifying `requires_grad=True` when defining my input tensors

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('dark_background')

# define rosenbrock function and gradient
a = 1
b = 5
def f(x):
   return (a - x[0]) ** 2 + b * (x[1] - x[0] ** 2) ** 2

def jac(x):
   dx1 = -2 * a + 4 * b * x[0] ** 3 - 4 * b * x[0] * x[1] + 2 * x[0]
   dx2 = 2 * b * (x[1] - x[0] ** 2)
   return np.array([dx1, dx2])

# create stochastic rosenbrock function and gradient
def f_rand(x):
   return f(x) * np.random.uniform(0.5, 1.5)

def jac_rand(x): return jac(x) * np.random.uniform(0.5, 1.5)

# use hand coded adam
x = np.array([0.1, 0.1])
x0 = x.copy()
j = jac_rand(x)
beta1=0.9
beta2=0.999
eps=1e-8
m = x * 0
v = x * 0
learning_rate = .1
for ii in range(200):
   m = (1 - beta1) * j + beta1 * m  # first  moment estimate.
   v = (1 - beta2) * (j ** 2) + beta2 * v  # second moment estimate.
   mhat = m / (1 - beta1 ** (ii + 1))  # bias correction.
   vhat = v / (1 - beta2 ** (ii + 1))
   x = x - learning_rate * mhat / (np.sqrt(vhat) + eps)
   x -= learning_rate * v
   j = jac_rand(x)

print('hand code finds optimal to be ', x, f(x))

# attempt to use pytorch
import torch
x_tensor = torch.tensor(x0, requires_grad=True)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([x_tensor], lr=learning_rate)

def closure():
   optimizer.zero_grad()
   loss = f_rand(x_tensor)
   loss.backward()
   return loss

for ii in range(200):
   optimizer.step(closure)

print('My PyTorch attempt found ', x_tensor, f(x_tensor))
```