# Why Tensor.clone().detach() is recommended when copying a tensor?

Tags: pytorch

What is the difference between copying a tensor using `torch.tensor(sourcetensor)` and `tensor.clone().detach()`?

---

Like `torch.tensor(srctsr)` always copies data, `tensor.clone().detach()` copies data too.

```py
x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
y1 = x.clone().detach()
y2 = torch.tensor(x)
x[0] = 0
print(y1, y2) # both are same
```

So they seem to be exactly the same. Below is the explanation given in the PyTorch documentation about `torch.tensor()` and `torch.clone().detach()`

> Therefore torch.tensor(x) is equivalent to x.clone().detach() and torch.tensor(x, requires_grad=True) is equivalent to x.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True). The equivalents using clone() and detach() are recommended.

So if they are equivalent to each other, why is `.clone().detach()` more preferred than the other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pytorch preferred way to copy a tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55266154/pytorch-preferred-way-to-copy-a-tensor)

Comment: Ok. "The x-axis is the dimension of tensor created, y-axis shows the time. The graph is in linear scale. As you can clearly see, the tensor() or new_tensor() takes more time compared to other three methods." But why does this happen?

Comment: You might be better off asking that in the official PyTorch forums because the developers can answer it better.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is described [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.tensor). I am adding some text (from the link) for the sake of completeness.

- torch.tensor() always copies data. If you have a Tensor data and want to avoid a copy, use torch.Tensor.requires_grad_() or torch.Tensor.detach().
- When data is a tensor x, torch.tensor() reads out ‘the data’ from whatever it is passed, and constructs a leaf variable. Therefore torch.tensor(x) is equivalent to x.clone().detach() and torch.tensor(x, requires_grad=True) is equivalent to x.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True). The equivalents using clone() and detach() are recommended.

Comment: I read it too. However, the difference is unclear. I added details.

Comment: I would like to do `x.clone().detach()` but how can I make `x` an actual tensor if `x` is an integer?

Comment: @tailsparkrabbitear you can make a tensor using `x_tensor = torch.tensor([x])`